# Tax income program if statement issue

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CardenasE_IncomeTax {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String username = "CardenasE";
        String realpass = "CarErick12!";
        boolean isMarried = true;
        boolean isNotMarried = false;

        double tax1 = 0;
        double tax2 = 0;
        double tax3 = 0;

        double RATE1 = 0.10;
        double RATE2 = 0.12;
        double RATE3 = 0.22;
        double RATE4 = 0.24;
        double RATE5 = 0.32;

        double limitSingle1 = 10000;
        double limitSingle2 = 40000;
        double limitSingle3 = 90000;
        double limitSingle4 = 165000;


        double limitMarried1 = 20000;
        double limitMarried2 = 80000;
        double limitMarried3 = 170000;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Username: ");
        String user = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Password:");
        String pass = input.nextLine();

        if (user.equals(username) && pass.equals(realpass)) {
            System.out.println("Login Successful!");
        } else if (!user.equals(username) || !pass.equals(realpass)) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Credentials!");
            return;
        }

        System.out.printf("%n What is your gross income?: ");
        double grossIncome = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Are you married?: (Type 's' for single and 'm' for married.) ");
        String maritalStatus = input.next();

        if (maritalStatus.equals("s")) {
            if (grossIncome <=limitSingle1)
                tax1 = grossIncome * RATE1;
            System.out.println("Your income is: " + tax1);
            return;
        } else if (grossIncome > limitSingle1 && grossIncome <= limitSingle2){
            tax2 = grossIncome * RATE2;
            System.out.println("Your income is: " + tax2);
        } 
    } 
}
```

When used the bracket for the first limit which is 10% from 0 to 10,000 it gives the proper solution, but I had another if statement which is greater than 10,000 but less than or equals to 40,000 and its set up as the first if statement but It gives out 0 as the answer, no matter how much numbers I put on.

Comment: a blunt comment: your indenting is not good. please fix it. readability can help prevent mistakes. I'd also recommend enclosing conditional blocks with actual `{}` block curlies. Not using curlies + bad indentation is an _easy_ source of errors.

Comment: Vague title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: I recommend [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to learn or review how to debug your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move the else if block of gross income, to the nested if in statement `if (grossIncome <=limitSingle1)`. Like this:

```
    if (maritalStatus.equals("s")) {
        if (grossIncome <=limitSingle1) {
            tax1 = grossIncome * RATE1;
            System.out.println("Your income is: " + tax1);
        } else if (grossIncome > limitSingle1 && grossIncome <= limitSingle2) {
            tax2 = grossIncome * RATE2;
            System.out.println("Your income is: " + tax2);
        }  
        return;
```

We can improve your code further by removing `tax1`, `tax2`, and `tax3` variables and only have `tax` variable. This is to reduce duplicate print outs.

```
    if (maritalStatus.equals("s")) {
        if (grossIncome <=limitSingle1) {
            tax = grossIncome * RATE1;
        } else if (grossIncome > limitSingle1 && grossIncome <= limitSingle2) {
            tax = grossIncome * RATE2;
        }  
        System.out.println("Your income is: " + tax);
        return;
```

As best practice, if you have values that shouldn't change. You should need to add the `final` keyword to avoid modification.

`double final RATE1 = 0.10;`

Furthermore, you can improve this by moving your constants in a `Constants.java` file. You can implement this too as a HashMap to do lookups.